# is it possible to search through all values of keys and return the key?

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net

here's my web.config:

```
<add key="SiteTitle" value="Breaking News, World News, and Multimedia"/>
    <add key="SiteName" value="New York Times"/>
<add key="somekey" value="somevalue"/>
```

is it possible to search through all values to find `"world news"` and return `"SiteTitle"` ?

i am using asp.net c#

thanks so much for your help

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm sure this can be done with a RegEx, but you can just search the contents of each KVP in the app settings: (Edited in response to your comment)

```
public string GetKeyThatHasMyValue (string Section, string ValueToFind)
{
    string Result = null;
    var Settings = (NameValueCollection)ConfigurationManager.GetSection (Section);
    foreach (string Key in Settings.Keys)
    {
        if (Settings[Key].Contains (ValueToFind))
        {
            Result = Key;
            break;
        }
    }

    return Result;
 }
```

**Edit:**
This is also assuming you are using app settings--otherwise use Eclyps19's code to grab the section in which you are interested and then use mine to look through them.

Comment: what else can you have besides app settings?

Answer (score 2):

You can use the System.Collections.Specialized namespace to pull out all of your key/value elements.

Add this:

```
using System.Collections.Specialized;
```

Then use something like this to grab the values:

```
NameValueCollection lstKeyValues;
lstKeyValues = (NameValueCollection) ConfigurationManager.GetSection("YourSectionHere");
```

You can then loop through it and pull the values you need