# how do i use a class without instantiating it?

Tags: c#, asp.net

I have class:

```
static class GetRole
    {
        public static string OfUser(string username)
        {
            string result="None";
            foreach (string key in WebConfigurationManager.AppSettings)
            {
                if (WebConfigurationManager.AppSettings[key].Contains(username))
                {
                    result = WebConfigurationManager.AppSettings[key];
                    break;
                }
            }

            return result;
        }
    }
```

i would like to use it lik ethis

```
string role = GetRole.OfUser(username);
```

or like this even better:

```
string role = GetRole(username);
```

how do i do this?

Comment: A static method will do exactly what you want. Have you tried it?

Comment: Isn't that how it's done ? ... What problem are you running into? What does the compiler say?

Comment: @mimi compiler says Error 7 'OfUser': cannot declare instance members in a static class C:\

Comment: The code you posted will not get that error.

Comment: @john thats the error im getting

Comment: Not with that code, you're not.

Comment: Regarding the error message you posted above - it that referencing line 7? If so, what's the content of line 7 in your code?

Comment: @mich this is line 7:public static string OfUser(string username)

Comment: i solved it :) just had to build it

Comment: You could have asked those of us helping you in [your previous question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7155264/is-it-possible-to-search-through-all-values-of-keys-and-return-the-key/7155314#7155314), too, since you instantly borrowed our code.

Comment: This string role = GetRole(username); doesn't work and it obviously defeats the purpose of Encapsulation.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

> i would like to use it like this

```
string role = GetRole.OfUser(username);
```

So do so; that appears to be correct. Did you try it?

> or like this even better:

```
string role = GetRole(username);
```

That won't work; you have to specify the method you're calling as well as what class it comes from.

If you had a `static void GetRole` inside the same class as the code that you're calling it from, then you could do that.

---

**However**, just because you can do something doesn't mean you should. The natural way to do "get the role of a user" is to call a method that belongs to the user itself. That in turn implies having a User class which you instantiate for each user.

Answer (score 3):

It's a little late but it can be done easily

```
using static MyProjectNameSpace.GetRole;
```

now you can use your method directly

```
OfUser("NewUserName");
```

Answer (score 1):

You pretty much nailed it with your first example of how to use it:

```
string role = GetRole.OfUser(username);
```

A static member indicates that it doesn't have an instance of whatever type is declaring it. The only thing that might be giving you trouble is that your class is internal; which means you can't access it from a different assembly. Try making it `public static class GetRole`.

Answer (score 0):

```
string role = GetRole.OfUser(username);
```

you are trying to use the variable of the method before it has been set... the method checks that `AppSettings[key].Contains(username))`and then returns an output so the method is expecting a string input like this...

`string role = GetRole.OfUser("NewUsername");`